# Polymer 2 iron-selector selected element doesn't update after the dom changes order of elements

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x

I have a component, which has 4 instances.

User clicks number 2, product B gets selected.

When the dom is re-ordered, later after he selects another option, these 4 instances of the component card-brick are re-ordered (because price changes, so this happens automatically in the flow) all good...  except for the fact that the selected element, which was number 2 , moved to position 1.

and... the 2nd element continues to be selected instead of product B!

The ui shows selected product D.

it seems that somehow polymer 2 is ignoring this selected attribute when repainting the DOM. how can I avoid this?

```
<iron-selector id="something-semantic" attr-for-selected="value" selected={{value}}>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[filteredProductosCategorias]]" as="productoCategoria" id="productoTipo">
        <div class="card-brick" value="[[productCategoria.id]]" tabindex="1" on-keyup="_seleccionaCategoria">
        </div>
    </template>
</iron-selector>
```

the selection is stick to previously selected element in the DOM order. how can I make this selected value to also update don dom changes??

any suggestion to overcome this problem?? users can be confused.

[image: image showing the problem visually]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that dom-repeat doesn't rebuild the elements inside, because that would be a heavy operation. It just assigns new values to child elements, meaning that iron-selector has no clue that the content has changed. In the example, you selected the second element, and after the re-sort, it's still the second element selected.

I'm confused in what `_selectCategory` does, because if it sets the category, then you probably don't even need `iron-selector`. I never used that element myself (and would never use it, because it's simple to write it myself). Anyway, if you re-sort using `_selectCategory`, then just set the new `value` property with `this.set()`.

Comment: Nevermind set the category, its just a renamed function. The dark side of this is that the element "is still selected" under the hood.. but not reflected on the UI. 

Removal of iron-selector , we at the team were thinking something along that way, remove iron-selector, as it seems to be a common issue, I found a couple of github issues on poylmer's repo. anyway, we need to look into it carefully as a lot of other components rely on the same functions. but, as you said, I totally agree that DIY would be much better. also, just saying, I really think I don't love Polymer.

Comment: Yeah, been working with Polymer for the last three years; upgrading from 1 to 2 was a treat. Some strange kinks in it still. Anyway, I would add a property to the items in `filteredProductsCategories`, like 'selected': 'selected' and then just add it as a class: `class$="[[selected]]"`. Finally add a ontap listener than changes the value of `selected` in all items (removing, then adding "selected" to the correct one).